# Pressing key not triggering script in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am learning java script at the moment and don't know the problem. The spaceship is not moving and there is no error? When I press `w` on my keyboard, it doesn't do anything. I think the problem is by `"document.onekeydown =function(e) {"` but I don't know what the problem is.

```js
let KEY_SPACE = false;
let KEY_W = false;
let KEY_S = false;
let canvas;
let ctx;
let backgroundImage = new Image();

let spaceship = {
  x: 50,
  y: 200,
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  src: 'img/spaceship.png'
};
let rock = {
  x: 100,
  y: 200,
  width: 200,
  height: 80,
  src: 'img/rock.png'
};


document.onekeydown = function(e) {
  console.log(e.keyCode);
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    KEY_SPACE = true;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 87) { ** I THINK THE PROBLEM IS HERE... **
      KEY_W = true;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 83) {
    KEY_S = true;
  }
};
document.onekeyup = function(e) {
  console.log(e.keyCode);
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    KEY_SPACE = false;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 87) {
    KEY_W = false;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 83) {
    KEY_S = false;
  }
};

function startgame() {
  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  loadImages();
  draw();
  setInterval(function update() {
    if (KEY_W) {
      spaceship.y -= 1;
    }

    if (KEY_S) {
      spaceship.y = 1;
    }
    console.log("Hi");
  }, 1000);



}

function loadImages() {
  backgroundImage.src = 'img/bg.png';
  spaceship.img = new Image();
  spaceship.img.src = spaceship.src;
  rock.img = new Image();
  rock.img.src = rock.src;
}

function draw() {
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  ctx.drawImage(backgroundImage, -100, 0, 874, 562);
  ctx.drawImage(spaceship.img, spaceship.x, spaceship.y, spaceship.width, spaceship.height);
}
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: darkgrey;
}
```

```html
<body onload="startgame()">
  <canvas id="canvas" width=" 720" height="480"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: It’s **onkeydown**; “on the event ‘keydown’, do this”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Oscar Umhin mentioned see this

```js
let KEY_SPACE = false;
let KEY_W = false;
let KEY_S = false;
let canvas;
let ctx;
let backgroundImage = new Image();

let spaceship = {
  x: 50,
  y: 200,
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  src: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSknVdXFn_hKNZqIkhf2n2mJ7seozp3S3pzJwQSFPJHCKVrgkEMJ1QOR8CLCSrOXbdGpE0&usqp=CAU'
};
let rock = {
  x: 100,
  y: 200,
  width: 200,
  height: 80,
  src: 'https://img.favpng.com/18/3/2/asteroid-space-rock-outer-space-comet-png-favpng-xTh5n6HtQqakzdAebMJ4Tn5Eb_t.jpg'
};


document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  console.log(e.keyCode);
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    KEY_SPACE = true;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 87) {
      KEY_W = true;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 83) {
    KEY_S = true;
  }
  update();
};
document.onkeyup = function(e) {
  console.log(e.keyCode);
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    KEY_SPACE = false;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 87) {
    KEY_W = false;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 83) {
    KEY_S = false;
  }
};

function startgame() {
  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  loadImages();
  draw();
}
function update() {
    if (KEY_W) {
      spaceship.y -= 1;
    }

    if (KEY_S) {
      spaceship.y = 1;
    }
    console.log("Hi");
  }
  
function loadImages() {
  backgroundImage.src = 'https://orsted.com/-/media/WWW/Images/Corp/Campaign/SpaceSafari/space-safari-background.png';
  spaceship.img = new Image();
  spaceship.img.src = spaceship.src;
  rock.img = new Image();
  rock.img.src = rock.src;
}

function draw() {
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  ctx.drawImage(backgroundImage, -100, 0, 874, 562);
  ctx.drawImage(spaceship.img, spaceship.x, spaceship.y, spaceship.width, spaceship.height);
}
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: darkgrey;
}
```

```html
<body onload="startgame()">
  <canvas id="canvas" width=" 720" height="480"></canvas>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

At first, the method `onekeydown()` seems not to exist, you probably mean `onkeydown()`?
Second, you only check the key input every second, this is not robust as you might miss inputs or produce input lags. Thus, you should consider to change the spaceship's value directly in the `onkeydown()` and `onkeyup()` methods.

Comment: Thank You soo much